# Есть ли способ создать алиас для имени таблицы в mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql

У меня есть база данных в mysql, которая используется приложениями. И я решил переименовать одну таблицу.

Вместе с переименованием таблицы я обновил все sql запросы в коде приложения, чтобы они использовали новое имя таблицы. Но приложения у меня обновляются не сразу, а в течении недели. Так что некоторые приложения все еще будут работать со старым кодом и будут посылать sql запросы со старым именем таблицы.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы таблица имела два имени? Чтобы она была доступа и по старому имени и по новому.

Вариант с view мне не подходит, потому что в таком случае будут работать только select запросы, а мне надо также update, delete, insert и вообще все остальные.

Comment: Я не пробовал, но может поможет. 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-updatability.html

Comment: Во view тоже можно инсертить и апдейтить...ну так...к сведению)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и правда view работает. Я что-то протупил. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Обычное view может быть обновляемым, как выяснилось.